# white screen during page transitions in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, cordova, redirect, jquery-mobile, flickr

We are developing one `jQueryMobile` app with `cordova` .After login successfully we are redirect to home page.But before home page loading `white screen` will be appeaser.We done R&d we found some solution like

```
.ui-page { -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; }
.ui-mobile, .ui-mobile body{
  background:#999;
}
$(document).on("mobileinit", function(){
    $.mobile.defaultDialogTransition = "none";
    $.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
});
```

We tried spinner also but white screen showing first then spinner will be appear

```
window.document.addEventListener("deviceready", appReady, false);
function appReady(){
     console.log("******02");
        spinnerplugin.show({
                    overlay: false,    // defaults to true
                    timeout: 30,       // defaults to 0 (no timeout)
                    fullscreen: true,  // defaults to false
                });
     }
```

So guide to us how to remove or hidden white screen while page transition.

Comment: Only use spinners if it is really necessary to provide feedback to the user. Is it really necessary to show a spinner if the homepage can load instantly? Also, you can leave the timeout of 30.

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively easy fix and I have to do this every time. You need to add the splash screen plugin from cordova:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Then add the following line to the config.xml in the root of your project folder:

```
<preference name="AutoHideSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

Then in your onload function or in the function that gets fired by your deviceready listener use this javascript to hide the splash screen:

```
navigator.splashscreen.hide();
```

You could also add a timeout to show the splash screen for longer if you need to:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    navigator.splashscreen.hide();
}, 2000); //Time to delay function in milliseconds
```

More information on the plugin can be found here:

https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this meta tag (**user-scalable=no**):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height"/>
```

and adding this to your css file:

```
.ui-page {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```